# Jenkins: how to get build started by, in editable email?

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using editable email notification in jenkins, I want to add started by details in email content.

I have added user detail by adding below line.

```
Started by user: ${BUILD_USER}
```

It give username if it is triggered by some user, but there are 3 possible ways as below.

```
Started by an SCM change
Started by timer
Started by <user>
```

In case of SCM and timer, ${BUILD_USER}  won't work.

Is there any way to display this details in email?

Comment: How about ```${BUILD_CAUSE}```?

Comment: with BUILD_CAUSE, getting proper message in case of SCM and TIMER, but for manual, i guess i have to add some condition.

Comment: Yes, you can add some conditions for the cases.

Comment: I tried to add condition withing email content, but editable email notification doesn't support condition.

Comment: You can use ```Flexible Publish Plugin```.  Adding a condtion like this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin?preview=/59506930/59899929/flex-pub2.png